# Margin: 0px auto; will not center element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my button 'Browser Portfolio' using margin: 0px auto; . Please could someone kindly explain why this is not working using the below html and CSS?

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Portfolio</h3>
        <div class="group1">
            <img src="http:....." style="height: 506px; width: 675px">

            <div class="group2">
                <h3>Client</h3>
                <h4>JPMorgan</h4>
                <h3>Role in Project</h3>
                <h4>Project Lead</h4>
                <h3>Project Included</h3>
                <h4>Mobile and Web Interface</h4>
                <a href="#">Browser</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group3">
            <a href="#">Browser Portfolio</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .portfolio .group3 {
        font-size: 0.9em;
        padding: 0.7em 1.5em;
        color: #5EC7E5;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: 1px solid red;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px auto;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: `.group3 { text-align: center; }`

Comment: Thank you. The solution works. However, for my own development and learning, I do not understand why. Are there certain prerequisites for using margin: 0px auto; ?

Comment: @mugman yes there are - display: block and an explicit width. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center elements using `margin: auto`, they have to use `display: block` and have an explicit width.

Adding this class to your css will make it work:

```
.group3 a {
    display: block;
    width: 110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `text-align: center` as other answers say.

See JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rbuzach0/

**Edit:** As you're asking why certain properties didn't inherit from your containing `<div>` to your `<a>`, here's a list (from the CSS2.1 spec, but that's all I could find in concise form) of which properties will inherit and which won't: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html

Check the "Inherited?" column. You'll see that neither Display nor Margin inherit.

Comment: Thank you beercohol. However, changing the 'display' element from inline-block to block in my original code, does not solve the problem? And I had already specified a width. Why is this?

Comment: No, your original css gave those attributes to the containing `div class="group3"` but they don't inherit down to child elements. You need to apply them to the `<a>` element directly. Also `inline-block` doesn't work with `margin: auto`

Comment: Please see updated answer for some more info on CSS inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Just add text-align:center to your .group3 element :

```
.group3 {
     text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8stggrpy/

When you have specified a width on the object that you have applied margin: 0 auto to, the object will sit centrally within it's parent container.

Comment: Thank you. The solution works. However, for my own development and learning, I do not understand why. Are there certain prerequisites for using margin: 0px auto; ?

Comment: Thank DJEBALI. However, I do not understand. In my original code I had already specified a width of the object and applied the margin, and as such, according to your answer, the object would therefore sit centrally within it's parent container; it did not? At least not until the text-align attribute was added, I do not understand the logic behind this. I have used margin: auto previously without text-align just fine, I'm wondering why this specific case is different.

Answer (score 0):

Define Text-Alignment in the CSS:

Add this line

```
.portfolio .group3 {
text-align: center;  //Missing in your code.
}
```

See Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2534uhxx/)